# Scoring System in a Flame (Flutter) Game Engine

Tags: flutter, flame

I am making a simple game using Flame (Flutter) game engine.

I want to implement a simple scoring system where the high score and the current score can be displayed at the end of the current round.

If the current score is higher than the previous high score than the high score is updated as the current score.

I also want to assign ranks to that scoring system where in each range of score, the player would be assigned a badge according to the score ranks, i.e. score between 5 - 10 is bronze, 11 - 15 is silver and so on.

How shall I realize this?

Thank you so much in advance.

I have read about some possible databases I could use here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/top-5-local-database-solutions-for-flutter-development-6351cd494070
but I haven't try anything yet because I have no idea how to implement said databases or any kind of database in Flame that would achieve the kind of scoring system I want for the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just keep the scores while the app is active, there's no need for any of those databases. You could simply keep the highest and current score as variables (that would update as you described) and use custom code to show a matching rank badge.

If you want to keep information about the highest (or latest, etc.) score even when the user closes the app, I suggest that you just use SharedPreferences https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences. This package from Flutter team allows you to store and read key value pairs, you could keep something like "highestScore", "lastScore", etc.